# Using styled-components to overwrite a react-slick styles

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

Hello im trying to overwrite styles in a reack-slicks component. Im trying to find a solution to change the dot but it's not working. Can someone help me?

```
export const SliderSlick = styled(BaseSliderSlick)`
  &&& .slick-dots {
    border: 1px solid red;
  }
`;
```

Comment: The problem is that your styles don't override the default one ? If it is the case, maybe you should use `!important`.. I know it's a bit dirty but for a specific case like this you can make an exception ?